# updating xmlnodes with foreach loop from datagridview

Tags: c#, xmlnode

I'm trying to update an XML node with new data extracted from datagridview.

The issue is that the code below takes only the last values and update it.

For example, I have 2 rows in the grid with arg1 and arg.2 values. When I extract it and iterate/ update the xmlnode, only the last row (row-1) data get updated in the xmlfile and the first one is ignored. Please advise.

```
public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    XmlDocument Newdoc = new XmlDocument();
    Newdoc.Load(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    int r = 0;

    foreach (XmlNode updatenode in Newdoc.SelectNodes(".//event[@type='2VO']"))

    {

        Newdoc.SelectSingleNode(".//@Arg1").InnerText = dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells["Arg1"].Value.ToString();
        Newdoc.SelectSingleNode(".//@Arg2").InnerText = dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells["Arg2"].Value.ToString();

        r++;
    }
    Newdoc.Save(@"C:\Users\namokhtar\Desktop\updatednew.xml");

}
```

Comment: You would need to reference the loop variable `updatenode` instead of starting over each iteration with `Newdoc`.

Comment: correct...thanks and it did work.